# What does this formula mean?

Tags: integration

What is this formula about? Does it make sense?

[image: t-shirt with formula]

I'm serious. I like this, but feel foolish when I'm asked what it *does* mean ;-)

Comment: this Q looks okay. are there specific reasons for putting it on hold? would adding the formula in MathJax help?

Comment: I can't help but feel like people sometimes vote off good questions because they seem amateur. I would also add that this is probably a physics problem, however.

Comment: In my opinion there is nothing wrong with this question, even though it is quite unusual for this forum. The OP simply wants to know whether the formula painted on his T-shirt makes any sense mathematically and if so, what is it exactly. (It seems to be something about fluid mechanics.)

Comment: This is a physics formula, try Physics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a formula for a force acting on a volume of fluid in a rotating frame of reference (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame#Newton.27s_second_law_in_the_two_frames)